# How to Setup WSO2 ELB with WSO2 Application Server in separate physical servers?

Tags: load-balancing, wso2

I have configured WSO2 ELB with WSO2 Application Server in local machine for three nodes. But when I have moved it to another remote machine then it could not able to clustering.
It gives an error "could not able to connect to member".

I have used this link http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ELB201/Setup+ELB+with+WSO2+Application+Server to setup in local machine.

Comment: You will have to provide a great deal more context to have a chance of a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you move to another remote machine, you should change IP and port appropriately in configurations. Remember that you have used port offset in the local machine. When port offset is applied every port is incremented with that value.

Comment: yes , i have already changed ip and port in "axis2.xml" configuration file.

Comment: Try changing catalina-server.xml, loadbalancer.conf and carbon.xml as well if required. (Every port should be affected when port offset is changed)

Comment: Thanx Maninda , i got the problem.
there is some configuration problem of domains in loadbalancer.conf file.